# Can't compile 64bit redis-server

Tags: redis, redis-server

I'm trying to compile the latest stable (2.8.19) version of Redis. Build is successfull as well as all tests, but unexpectedly server runs on 32bit arch.
Log entries:

```
# Warning: 32 bit instance detected but no memory limit set. Setting 3 GB maxmemory limit with 'noeviction' policy now.  
Redis 2.8.19 (00000000/0) 32 bit  
Running in stand alone mode  
Port: 6582  
PID: 2381
```

Redis-cli `INFO` display arch_bits:32. Previous instance (version 2.4.6) works well on arch_bits 64, but I don't know which way it was installed.

OS version info:

```
root:~# uname -a
Linux localhost 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 22:49:26 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.1
Codename:       squeeze

root:~# arch
x86_64
```

What are the ways to fix this issue and run latest redis as 64bit?

**UPD**
Despite above commands output, `dpkg --print-architecture` returns `i386` and all packages in system are `all` or `i386`. Only redis-server 2.4.*, installed as a package, is strangely `ia64`.
What can I do in this situation? The server was setup long time ago by another person, and I is still too newbie in Unix.

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: Just by instructions provided, for example, on Redis site
`$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.19.tar.gz  

$ tar xzf redis-2.8.19.tar.gz  

$ cd redis-2.8.19  

$ make`

Comment: Can you try with `make distclean` and `make` again?

Comment: Of course. Several times with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, my server needs a full migration from 32 to 64-bit architeture.
Current task solved by downloading compiled 64-bit DEB-package and installing it manually.